# Reconfigure the Search Component in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, enterprise-search

One of my team members accidently deleted the WSS_Search_ServerName contentd db from the SSMS studio. So, I would like to recreate/reinstall 
**the search components only** for my SP 2010 server.

Can i repair the sharepoint 2010 , by going to the "Programs n features" and click on the change/uninstall ?

If I perform the above, will I lose all my existing data/sites/ lists/docu libs etc? 
[image: sp2010install]

[image: WSS_SEARCHDB_MISSING]

When I tried to create a  new srch srv appln, using powershell as mentioned in the Russmax blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2009/10/20/sharepoint-2010-configuring-search-service-application-using-powershell.aspx
I am getting the error , timerjob running out error message.

[image: ps_srch_srv_appln_failed]

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not recommend to repair SharePoint via Control Panel.

As the database is about search, to solve this issue quickly, you can create a new search service application instead of the old one.

Comment: but when i tried to create a new search service appln, from central admin, it hangs, even after 12+ hours.it was still in the same state. So, am unabe to create a new srch srv appln. when i checked the SSMS in the back end,  the 3 srch DBs were created, but in the CA page, its still in the process of  srch srvice applm creation ONLY!

Comment: check the CPU and memory of your SharePoint server and SQL server, make sure they are enough. In addition, you can try to use PowerShell command to create a new search service application.[https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jjameson/2011/02/28/powershell-script-to-configure-search-in-sharepoint-server-2010/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jjameson/2011/02/28/powershell-script-to-configure-search-in-sharepoint-server-2010/)

Comment: i tried using the powershell ysday night, 10 pm and it didnt even complete till today morning at 1045 am. so, its more than 12 hrs !. But now, when i checked again,  i am getting the error :                       $searchapp = new-spenterprisesearchserviceapplication -n
ame IPSL_SearchServiceApplication -applicationpool $app
New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication : The timer job did not complete running within the allotted time.
what may be the exact issue ?

Comment: could you create other service applications except search service application? open Services, find SharePoint Timer Service, make sure the identify of the service is farm account and restart it.

Comment: i have tried many options, but nothing worked and at last i removed SP an reinstalled SP 2010. And the search is working. But one more issue i am facing is, teh search is working for the system account only not for normal accounts like site collec admin accounts and other user accounts. Didnt understand why this issue is popped up now!